# Unknown intermittent crash due dragging and dropping in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, crash, valgrind

I've been trying to find this bug for over a day now and I'm starting to go mad... I have re-written and closely examined the code for dragging and dropping to no avail.

It occurs in the main Qt event loop a.exec() with the stack trace from valgrind shown below. It can sometimes crash on a QMutex::Lock() (I only use one QThread (main qt event loop), all other threads are contained in the backend and are safe)

As the bug took more than an hour to show up using the mouse myself, I wrote a function that moves the mouse about pressing, releasing, clicking, double clicking. This causes the bug to occur within about ten minutes.

I'd post some code up but their is a few thousand lines for the drag and drop stuff (it works perfectly apart from this annoying bug)

The drag can occur in two types of item and is basically the same for both. On the mouse move event, the drag->exec() is called.

I am using a subclassed mime data to allow it to contain what I require.

Any help would be amazing...

```
Invalid read of size 8
  in main in Src/Program/main.cpp:77
Address 0x40 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  
  1: QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject*, QEvent*, int) in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
  2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
  3: QApplication::x11ClientMessage(QWidget*, _XEvent*, bool) in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
  4: QApplication::x11ProcessEvent(_XEvent*) in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
  5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
  6: g_main_context_dispatch in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3
  7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3
  8: g_main_context_iteration in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3
  9: QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags&lt;QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag&gt;) in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
  10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.1
  11: QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags&lt;QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag&gt;) in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
  12: QEventLoop::exec(QFlags&lt;QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag&gt;) in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
  13: QCoreApplication::exec() in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
  14: main in
```

Main:

```
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

    if (testing)
    {
      UnitTest::RunAllTests();
      return 0;
    }

    MainWindow w(debug, testing);
    w.show();
    w.InitialiseGUI();
    return a.exec();   <- line 77
```

When drag object is created:

```
void ElementItem::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
  if
      (
       (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) &&
       ((event->pos() - _drag_start_position).manhattanLength() > DRAG_START_DISTANCE)
       )
  {

    _control_and_status->_drag_control_object->NotifyDragStarted();

    try
    {

      // Ensure that if something goes wrong and old widget does not get deleted.
      // create a new drag object
      _drag = new QDrag(this);

      // create a custom mime type (subclass of QMimeType)
      WidgetMimeType *mimeData = new WidgetMimeType;

      ChainWidgetBase * base_widget = LoadElementAndWidget();

      // Set the widget as this object
      if (base_widget)
      {
        mimeData->_widget = (QWidget *) base_widget;
        mimeData->_delete_on_failure = true;
        mimeData->_widget_deletion_required = &_widget_deletion_required;
      }
      else
      {
        delete _drag;
        _drag = NULL;
        throw GeneralException(ErrorReporting::ERROR_IN_DROPPABLE_CONTAINER, "Null widget");
      }

      _drag->setMimeData(mimeData);

      Qt::DropAction dropAction = _drag->exec();

    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }

    DragStopped();
  }
}
```

This is one of the places where the drag object is created, there are 3 more that do different things, but use the same method

Subclassed mime data:

```
#pragma once
#include <QtGui>

class WidgetMimeType : public QMimeData
{
public:
  WidgetMimeType():
    _widget(NULL),
    _delete_on_failure(false),
    _deletion_required_dummy(false),
    _widget_deletion_required(&_deletion_required_dummy)
  {
  }

  ~WidgetMimeType()
  {
  }

  QWidget * _widget;
  bool _delete_on_failure;
  bool _deletion_required_dummy;
  bool * _widget_deletion_required;
};
```

EDIT: I have added the QT source, location of the crash:

```
void QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event, int priority)
{
    if (receiver == 0) {
        qWarning("QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver");
        delete event;
        return;
    }

    QThreadData * volatile * pdata = &receiver->d_func()->threadData;
    QThreadData *data = *pdata; <--- CRASHES HERE
    if (!data) {
        // posting during destruction? just delete the event to prevent a leak
        delete event;
        return;
    }

    // lock the post event mutex
    data->postEventList.mutex.lock();

    // if object has moved to another thread, follow it
    while (data != *pdata) {
        data->postEventList.mutex.unlock();

        data = *pdata;
        if (!data) {
            // posting during destruction? just delete the event to prevent a leak
            delete event;
            return;
        }

        data->postEventList.mutex.lock();
    }
```

The crash occurs on the line shown above, where it says <---- CRASH HERE. Its is from dereferencing a pointer. Is this enough information to determine what is going on?

Comment: Line 77, and some context around it, in Src/Program/main.cpp might be informative. Could you post that?

Comment: the other solution is to not drag and drop :p

Comment: And show us your code around creating your `QDrag` object.

Comment: "I am using a subclassed mime data to allow it to contain what I require." Show us that too.

Comment: There is about zero chance of finding a bug like this by eyeballing a small portion of the code. I suggest using a debug build of Qt. Running under a debugger will help you find which data Qt is trying to access. Then try to find which piece of code could possibly fill it with garbagen

Comment: Sounds like 1. a trashed pointer, or 2. bad RAM.

Comment: I've had problems with automatic deletions before, could you expand on that delete_on_failure and what seems you passing a stack variable as a pointer? `_widget_deletion_required(&_deletion_required_dummy)`

Comment: An address like `0x40` usually is from code like `struct_ptr->some_field`, where `some_field` is at offset 0x40 from the start of the struct, and the pointer is NULL.

Comment: The delete on failure, is a pointer to a bool that is used to determine if the widget is required to be deleted, due to it not being dropped, or coming from a slot where it it is not dropped it will remain there. It is a pointer, as the mime data has to be constant.

Comment: I suspect your code does things synchronously in mouseMoveEvent that shouldn't happen during event handling. E.g., triggering the deletion of the widget that currently processes the mouseMoveEvent will crash. That deletionRequired stuff in WidgetMimeType looks suspicious in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

`Qt::DropAction dropAction = _drag->exec();` this is line at which your code may crash. I did not read your code fully but I assume that after dragging widget you are deleting the original widget using deleteLater() function. IF this the case then for window platform tit will work fine because of`_drag->exec()` will block events and if it is mac or Linux it will not block the events. So that, So that event of `_drag->exec()` get the null pointer while executing the event.

I know this `deleteLater()` execute when the object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop.

In generally, deleteLater() is execute the before _drag->exec() complete.